# Extract rows with specific element in the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, with one of its columns being column of lists. I want to extract rows that have a specific element in corresponding list. (For example, DF is dataframe and DF['a'] is Series of lists. Then I want to find rows where there is an X element in corresponding DF['a'] list). How can I do it?

Comment: please post a data sample to replicate, else we will just be guessing and you may not find a relevant answer. Check [how to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({             
   'a' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','X'],                                                                                                                                                 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df[df.a == 'X']

print(df)

   a
0  X
3  X
6  X
```